# Current user as a class-level property in Objective-C and Swift

Tags: object-oriented, objective-c, swift, static

I was recently tasked with architecting a user/profile object in Objective-C and wanted the ability to access a static instance from the class level, similar in style to the way Parse manages their current user (a static variable on a class, not a singleton).  With Parse, I can call a class method to return the current user object if a user is logged in, or `nil` if there is no current user session with `[PFUser currentUser]`.

I architected my class like so:

User.h

```
@interface User : NSObject

/// Returns the current user if logged in, or nil if logged out
+ (User *)currentUser;

/// Sets the current user, call this on login
+ (void)setCurrentUser:(NSDictionary *)userInfo;

/// Removes the current user, call this on logout
+ (void)removeCurrentUser;

// Getters

/// Returns the user's name if logged in, nil if logged out
@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSString *name;

@end
```

User.m

```
@interface User ()

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *address;

@end

@implementation User

#pragma mark - Static Variables

static User *currentUser;

#pragma mark - Static Object Setters and Getters

+ (User *)currentUser
{
    return currentUser;
}

+ (void)setCurrentUser:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    currentUser = [[User alloc] initWithDictionary:userInfo];
}

+ (void)removeCurrentUser
{
    currentUser = nil;
}

#pragma init

- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        NSString *name = userInfo[@"name"];
        NSString *address = userInfo[@"address"];

        if (!name || !address ) { return nil; }

        _name = name;
        _address = address;
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

This works well.  I have a single static `User` instance which can be non-nil if a user is logged in, and `nil` if the user is logged out.  I can access this object from anywhere with `[User currentUser]` without a singleton.

Now as an additional challenge I'm trying to translate this type of pattern into Swift.  Here is my fist pass:

```
public class User {

    // Private Properties
    private var name: String?
    private var address: String?

    // Private instance of User
    private static var user: User?

    // Class Functions

    public class func currentUser() -> User? {
        return self.user
    }

    public class func setCurrentUser(userInfo: [String : AnyObject]) {
        self.user = User(dictionary: userInfo)
    }

    public class func removeCurrentUser() {
        self.user = nil
    }

    // Instance methods

    public func getName() -> String? {
        return self.name
    }

    // Private

    private convenience init?(dictionary: [String : AnyObject]) {
        self.init()

        guard let name = dictionary["name"] as? String else { return nil }
        guard let address = dictionary["address"] as? String else { return nil }

        self.name = name
        self.address = address
    }
}
```

This works but doesn't feel "Swifty" enough.

Questions:

Is there a way to expose a public getter on a private property (sort of like a property redeclaration through a class extension in Objective-C)?  Or do I need to write an additional accessor.

Does declaring my private `User` object as `private static` ensure that it can only be accessed on the class level and not on the instance level?  Is this variable really `static` like it would be in C or Objective-C?

Can a `User` setter and getter be added/modified to remove the need for `setCurrentUser` and `removeCurrentUser`?

I am open to optimizations in both my Swift and Objective-C code.

Answer (score 2):

(I am referring to the Swift code only.)

You can declare a property as

```
public private(set) var name: String?
```

to make it public read-only, but internally read-write. That makes
the additional accessor `getName()` obsolete.

If the property is only assigned in the init method and never
changed later, you can simply make it constant:

```
public let name: String?
```

Since the initializer ensures that both name and address are assigned
a value, you don't have to declare them as optionals.

The `currentUser()`, `setCurrentUser()`, `removeCurrentUser()`
methods can be replaced by a static property

```
public static var currentUser: User?
```

if you make the initializer public. `static` means `class final`,
i.e. it is a property of the type (and not an instance) and cannot
be overridden in subclasses.

The two `guard` statements can be combined into one.

The class then looks like this:

```
public class User {

    public static var currentUser: User?

    public let name: String
    public let address: String

    public init?(dictionary: [String : AnyObject]) {

        guard let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
            let address = dictionary["address"] as? String
        else { return nil }

        self.name = name
        self.address = address
    }
}
```

The "current user" can now be set, retrieved, and unset like this:

```
User.currentUser = User(dictionary: ...)
if let user = User.currentUser {
    // ...
}
User.currentUser = nil
```

If you change the initializer to

```
public init?(dictionary: [String : Any])
```

then you can pass a native Swift dictionary without casting, e.g.

```
User.currentUser = User(dictionary: ["name": "Joe", "address": "San Francisco"])
```

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C, you could define a class property like this,

```
@interface User : NSObject

@property (class, nonatomic, strong) User *currentUser;     

@end
```

Maybe that's what you want.

For the static variable, yes, it could be accessed in both class and instance level in its own namespace.

Comment: This question was written before class properties were announced in Objective-C.  Either way, I'm looking for a Swift answer.

Comment: @JAL, Based on the question, you're looking for either. "I am open to optimizations in both my Swift and Objective-C code." It's a valid suggestion, but to your point, I agree. It's a tangential answer because it's a solution that hadn't existed prior.